# Super administrator db name

Tags: admin, wpdb

As I cant test this(cant find any docs and dont have an multisite setup) I need to know the db name of the Super Administrator. So how is this role stored inside the wp db?

It's probably something like 'super_administrator'...?

Answer (score 0):

The administrator role is defined by the capabilities the user has. Those are stored in the `wp_user_meta` table for each user. If you're on multisite, an additional set of capabilities is assigned to a Super Admin.

[The Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Additional_Admin_Capabilities) tells us what capabilities we can check for in code to see if a user is an admin.

Comment: I know all of this, but I am looking for the db name of the super administrator role...example: adminstrator,editor, subscriber etc so the name that is stored inside the db(user -> roles)

Comment: I've set up a test multisite install with a single test site, an admin user on the site, and an additional network admin. All three of them show up in the `user_capabilities` column as "administrator".